# Can an empty sequence be generated from any nonempty set?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Given some nonempty set $\Sigma$ can we always generate the empty sequence $\epsilon$ from the elements of $\Sigma$ ? Is that an axiom of sorts? In other words, how do we conclude that such a thing is "do-able"?

Comment: What is a sequence? The empty set is always a subset of $\Sigma$.

Comment: A sequence in $\Sigma$ is an ordered list of elements of $\Sigma$.

Comment: The answers to your question in [MSE question 3124049](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3124049) "The definition of the empty string" didn't satisfy you?

Comment: Yes, it did not satisfy me.

Answer (score 1):

The empty sequence is the empty set which is a subset of every set, empty or not.

Likewise, every function with empty domain is the empty set and injective.  Thus the empty set is countable even though there are no elements in the empty set to count.

The empty space is uniquely determined as being the only space with exactly one open set and is metrizable by the empty metric.

Indeed, emptiness has many wondrous properties.